# How do you revert (roll back) to an earlier version of a committed file in CVS

Tags: cvs

Let's take for example a single file committed in CVS with the following history.

test.cpp 
rev 1.1
rev 1.2
rev 1.3

How do I revert to rev 1.2 discarding the changes in 1.3 and then continue to make modification from that point on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

cvs update -j 1.3 -j 1.2 test.cpp